# Bad File Name and number,

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub projectActivity()

Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Const StartRow As Long = 6
Dim LastRow As Long
Const StartC As Long = 1
Dim LastC As Long
Dim MyValue As Variant
Dim FileName As String

Let FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ProjectActivity77st.csv"



Open FileName For Output As #1

LastC = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For r = StartRow To LastRow
 For c = StartC To LastC
  
  MyValue = MyValue & Cells(r, c).Value & ";"
  

  Next c
  
 MyValue = Left(MyValue, Len(MyValue) - 1)
 
 Print #1, MyValue
 
 MyValue = ""
 
Next r

Close #1

End Sub
```

I did not see any problem with my code, but error message "Bad File Name or Number" comes up all the time, driving me nut, can anybody help ?thanks

Comment: Change `Open FileName For Output As #1` to `Dim FF as Integer`. Under that, `FF = FreeFile`. Under that, `Open FileName For Output As #FF` (example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function#example). Wherever you use #1, replace that with #FF.

Comment: @Blackcat FF is an integer. VBA does not interpret #FF as hex. You can try it out. VBA understands that `Dim FF as Integer` means FF is an integer. FF is given the next free file integer available. Then, VBA uses #5 if FF is 5 for file number in the `open` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Export To CSV Using the Open Statement

[image]

- The error occurred because file number 1 was already taken by another file. This could have happened if an error occurred before you closed the file.
- To prevent using an already taken file number you can use the [FreeFile function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function).
- To prevent leaving the file open (e.g. in case of an error), you can implement some error handling.
- The following code deals with the fore-mentioned and with a few other 'surprises lurking'.
- To boost efficiency, you should reference the whole range, write its values to an array, and loop over the elements of the array instead over the cells of the range (not covered in the following code).

```vb
Sub ExportProjectActivityToCSV()
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "ProjectActivity77st.csv"
    Const COLUMN_DELIMITER As String = ";"
    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 6
    Const FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    If Not TypeOf sh Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "The workbook's active sheet """ & sh.Name _
            & """ is not a worksheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim LastRow As Long:
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, FIRST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < HEADER_ROW Then
        MsgBox "There is no data in column " & FIRST_COLUMN & " below " _
            & " row " & HEADER_ROW & " (inclusive).", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim LastCol As Long:
    LastCol = sh.Cells(HEADER_ROW, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol < FIRST_COLUMN Then
        MsgBox "There is no data in row " & HEADER_ROW & " to the right of" _
            & " column " & FIRST_COLUMN & " (inclusive).", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FilePath As String:
    FilePath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & DST_FILE_NAME
    
    Dim cdLen As Long: cdLen = Len(COLUMN_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim FileNum As Long: FileNum = FreeFile
    
    Open FilePath For Output As #FileNum
        
    Dim MyString As String, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = HEADER_ROW To LastRow
        For c = FIRST_COLUMN To LastCol
            MyString = MyString _
                & CStr(sh.Cells(r, c).Value) & COLUMN_DELIMITER
        Next c
        MyString = Left(MyString, Len(MyString) - cdLen)
        Print #FileNum, MyString
        ' To get rid of the trailing new line, instead of the previous line,
        ' you could do (note the semicolon):
'        If r = LastRow Then
'            Print #1, MyString;
'        Else
'            Print #1, MyString
'        End If
        MyString = "" ' reset for the next iteration (row)
    Next r
    
ProcExit:
    ' Make sure the file gets closed:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if an error occurred before 'Open'
        Close #FileNum
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Im not sure that the cause is an occupied filenumber